# Powershell ADP API Token

Tags: powershell, rest, invoke-restmethod, adp-api

I am running the following in Powershell. I am getting an error returned that "The given client credentials were not valid". I am trying to do the first step of using the API, generating the access token. I have confirmed that I have a valid client_id and client_secret.

This is working in Postman, but I am not seeing what I have wrong in Powershell. Help!

```
$URLTokenV2="https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"
$Json= @{
    client_id='xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
    client_secret='xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
$Json=$Json | ConvertTo-Json
$Cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "CN=CertCN*"}
$Response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLTokenV2 -Method Post -Body $Json -Certificate $Cert -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

I have tried the same with Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest. I get the same result for both, that the client credentials are not valid.

Responses are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-ContentType 'application/json'` ?

Comment: The documentation for the API call states it is supposed to be x-www-form-urlencoded. At your suggestion I tried application/json just for kicks. I got the same result as before. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Try passing the `grant_type` query parameter in the body (add it to the `$JSON` hashtable) instead of as part of the URI.

Comment: Well, I got that to work, but the URL is a little different. The URL is now "https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?" It didn't work previously without the '?'

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ADP's public documentation](https://developers.adp.com/articles/guide/auth-process-data-conn-request-access-token):

> In general, your consumer application **should pass the client_id and
> client_secret parameters in the HTTP Authorization header using the
> HTTP Basic authentication scheme** (or other designated scheme). The
> client_id and client_secret must be separated by a single colon (":")
> character and encoded within a base64-encoded string, as required by
> IETF RFC 2617.
>
> Your consumer application must:
>
> - Send the request with the X.509 certificate provided during registration.
> - Pass all parameters in a URL-encoded format with UTF-8 character encoding as specified by the HTTP header Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The actual request might look like
>   the following example:

> ```
>  POST /auth/oauth/v2/token HTTP/1.1
>  Host: accounts.adp.com
>  Authorization: Basic QURQVGFibGV0OnRoZXRhYmxldHBhc3N3b3Jk
>  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>  grant_type=client_credentials
> ```

So you need to do something like this instead:

```
$URLTokenV2 = 'https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token'

# Prepare Basic Authentication header payload (the base64 part)
$AuthorizationValue = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('xxxxxxxxx-client-id-xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxx-client-secret-xxxxxxxxxxxx')
)

$Cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "CN=CertCN*"}

# Prepare request body - no need to explicitly convert to JSON 
$Body = @{
  grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

# Pass the `Authorization` header value with the payload we calculate from the id + secret
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLTokenV2 -Method Post -Header @{ Authorization = "Basic ${AuthorizationValue}" } -Body $Body -Certificate $Cert -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment from Mathias I now have the following working

```
$URLTokenV2="https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?"
$Json= @{
     client_id='xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
     client_secret='xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
     grant_type='client_credentials'
}
$Response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URLTokenV2 -Method Post -Body $Json -Certificate $Cert -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

I had tried "grant_type='client_credentials'" as a part of the Json array, but this time when I tried it I accidentally left the '?' in the URL. I also had to remove the line to convertto-Json. After that it worked.